# Does this alignment of the equations look weird?

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

Does this alignment look weird? I hope this use of the bracket would make sense. I'm considering another way to display such as  \begin{gathered} etc...

[image]

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\label{Test}
m(t)\ddot{\text{p}}&=\lambda(t)\text{u},\quad
\left\{ 
  \begin{alignedat}{2}   
    m(t)&=m+a_{load} m(1-\text{e}^{-\frac{t}{T}}) \\   
    \lambda(t)&=\text{e}^{-\frac{t}{T}}
  \end{alignedat} 
\right.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Here's a minimal example for you to compile. Please align them simply taking small space as you can:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\label{Test}

m(t)\ddot{\text{p}}&=\lambda(t)\text{u},\\ 
m(t)&=m+a_{load} m(1-\text{e}^{-\frac{t}{T}}),\\
\lambda(t)&=\text{e}^{-\frac{t}{T}}.

\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: This looks perfectly reasonable to me, but I'm not a professional mathematician.  Setting it in three lines with `gather` (if that's what you mean) would remove the implied relationship between what's on the left and what's on the right.  But you could use `cases` instead of `aligned` and then you wouldn't need the explicit brace.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks a lot. I meant by \gather that the positions are the same as this post but a vertical line is in-between and a big bracket holds them just like mentioning a domain in topology. And I find it hard to convey what we imagine only by sentences, so it would be helpful if you answer this post :)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide code we can compile i.e. a complete minimal example.

Comment: @cfr Thank you. I added :)

Comment: note that asking for notation is off topic here. once you have decided a notation you can ask how to do it in tex

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `\text`, but `\mathrm`. Why? Try

```
\begin{theorem}
Here $\text{e}^2$ will be in italics
\end{theorem}
```

(this assumes you have such a `\newtheorem` defined).

<sup>Of course I'd never use `\mathrm{e}` for the famous Bernoulli's number (wrongly called Euler's number), but it's a different topic.</sup>

Similarly, `_{load}` is wrong and should be `_{\mathrm{load}}`.

You don't need the outer `aligned` and `alignedat` can be more simply `aligned`. Also `\qquad` seems better, so the distance is greater.

I'd also prefer `-1/T` rather than the two-story fractions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{Test}
m(t)\ddot{\mathrm{p}}=\lambda(t)\mathrm{u},
\qquad
\left\{
  \begin{aligned}
    m(t)       &=m+a_{\mathrm{load}} m(1-\mathrm{e}^{-1/T}) \\   
    \lambda(t) &= \mathrm{e}^{-1/T}
  \end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're under severe space constraints, such as two-column printing, you can stack the two parts:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{Test}
\begin{gathered}
m(t)\ddot{\mathrm{p}}=\lambda(t)\mathrm{u},
\\[1ex]
\left\{
  \begin{aligned}
    m(t)       &=m+a_{\mathrm{load}} m(1-\mathrm{e}^{-1/T}) \\   
    \lambda(t) &= \mathrm{e}^{-1/T}
  \end{aligned}
\right.
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]